# venn diagram related with percentage of three subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Q1) In a colony 50% families have a car whereas 75 families have only two-wheelers, 25% families have neither a car nor a two-wheeler and 40 % families have both car and two wheeler. How many families are there in the colony?

Options a) 600 b) 200 c) 150 d) 300

Q2) In asurvey it is found that 65% of the residents of colony 'X' have two wheelers, while 45% of the residents have four-wheelers, 20% of the residents do not have any one of these and 70 residents have only two-wheelers.

```
1) How many residents were Surveyed?
   a) 200 b) 100 c) 150 d) 225

2) How many residents have two-wheelers ?
   a) 70  b) 60  c) 150 d) 130

3) How many residents do not have any one of these?
   a) 20  b) 40  c) 30  d) 60

4) How many residents have exactly one vehicle ?
   a) 50  b) 150 c) 100 d) 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1 Venn diagram:

```
+--------------------------------+
|                                | 
| +---<car>--50%--+              |
| |               |              |
| | y%?      +--------------+    |
| |          | 40%|   75    |    |
| +----------|----+   x%    |    |
|            |              |    |
|            +----<bike>----+    |
|                   \            |
|                    \ z%        |
|      <nada> 25%   -/           |
+--------------------------------+
```

**Hint:** What is the percentage of those who do not own a car?
What cases or to consider for them?
How does their percentage split?

Q2 Venn diagram

```
+-------------------------------+
|          +-------<4>-45%--+   |
|          |                |   |
|          |                |   |
| +65%-<2>-|---+            |   |
| |        |   |            |   |
| |        +----------------+   |
| | 70         |                |
| |            |     <nix>      |
| +------------+      20%       |
+-------------------------------+
```